# How do you Convert a .sp1 file into a Shapefile

Tags: basic-license-level

I was previously able to convert .sp1 files into shapefiles, but that was last February. I can only remember how to do some of it.

How do you convert them into shapefiles ?  These are preplot receiver / source points as I am using ArcView 9.3

Comment: Do you have a link to sp1 files? Not familiar with the format.

Comment: i have it downloaded onto my drive. I don't know what you mean by a link.

Comment: Can you give some details about what are the contents of the file, are the values comma/semi-colon or space delimited; what data they capture (i.e. do they have X, Y data within it) etc etc...this will help us refer a tool to you. like @Dan, I've also not heard about this format (SP1).

Comment: also, what software produced the file

Comment: This is what it looks like in the columns. No comma. they capture x/y, from the gps coordinates. I never heard of sp1 til last Feb and haven't had to deal with it since. I'm just trying to figure it out so I can write it down for the next time I run into this file again. Re: which program created this? I dont know, I'm thinking ArcVIEW. ---- Why was I "downgraded" when I don't know which info to put out when I've never had to deal with this type of file before. Thanks, Z G69 690179 5629640 426159 0 -- G69 690180 5628084 427715 0 --G69 690181 5626528 429271 0

Comment: +1 for unearthing (!) a new format. sp1 seems to be a National Geodetic Survey format. See details for sp3 - http://igscb.jpl.nasa.gov/igscb/data/format/sp3_docu.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ArcGIS then the Data Interop extension would be able to solve this.

Create a Spatial ETL tool using CSV as the source format and a space character as the delimiter. Then use a transformer (2DPointReplacer) to convert them to points. A 5 minute job if you have that extension.

Comment: Hey Mark, 

I don't have that extension nor license for Data interop extension.  That is something you need to purchase from what it looks, right? 

Z